# Android Tablayout tabs with notification badge like whatsApp

Tags: android, badge, android-tablayout

I want to implement notification badge with `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`. I had tried my best effort to implement it but fails.

Any help would by greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just create a relative layout for the tab and add textview in it. Then on run time change its text.

Comment: would you provide, me a demo of the app?? as i had tried my every possible way to do this.

Comment: Post your tabs code.Main tab activity.

Comment: https://github.com/natuan241/Android-Design-Support-Library-Sample, I am using the following code for navigation

Comment: Add a customview to your tablayout tabs and you can attach a badge from  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger easily

Comment: Benoit, viewbadger didn't work for TabLayout..you can check it

Comment: @Arjunsharma im using Tablayout, and my badge is at the last of my Tabs because im using only one Tab id , idont know how to give each tab a diffrent id ,plz help

Comment: you can also use this library https://github.com/rahimlis/badgedtablayout

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896907/can-a-custom-view-be-used-as-a-tabitem/51151541#51151541

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution to this was using https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger and setting a custom view to each tab:

My tabs have only icons so I used ImageView, but I believe you can use any other view, check https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/README.markdown:

```
private BadgeView badge;
```

---

```
Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
tab.setCustomView(imageView);
badge = new BadgeView(context, imageView);
```

Comment: this library is deprecated now

Comment: it works for me thanks!

Answer (score 39):

**EDIT: UPDATE**

With the newest release of the `Material Components`, the Android team now offers an official `BadgeDrawable` to be used on the `TabLayout` to achieve the asked result. It is part of the v1.1.0-alpha07 update. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha07

The usage is very simple and can be done as following:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).showBadge().setNumber(1);
```

See the integration in the material components demo app:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/111cd001f5302bd6899f181ab7ccea2fd4002f63#diff-bf3e9a8a208f0ecab05088823fba99c4R239

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I tried some of the above mentioned solutions, but they did not deliver proper results. If you take a closer look in the `TabLayout` implementation you will realize that the `TabView` will try to get the textView and iconView from the `CustomView` if applied.

So instead of doing some hacky implementations I rather came up with a layout equal to the one from the original `TabView` but an additional view which can have a badge.

So you will need the badged_tab.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/badgeCotainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notifications_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And some sort of notification background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

When adding your tab programatically just call

```
tab.setCustomView(R.layout.badged_tab);
```

And then you can show / hide / set a badge cound at any time via:

```
if(tab != null && tab.getCustomView() != null) {
    TextView b = (TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.badge);
    if(b != null) {
        b.setText(notifications + "");
    }
    View v = tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.badgeCotainer);
    if(v != null) {
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this approach, and it worked for me. I adapted this solution to add a custom view that contained the badge, and then simply setCustomView(null) to remove it when it wasn't needed in the UI. Creating a custom view that has the same spacings and margins is important so you get a seamless transition to the default view for the respective tab. I used this successfully with TabLayouts. Alternatively, you can use a custom view on all tabs and switch between badge and non-badged layouts as required if you're having trouble with UI consistency between them.

Comment: Best solution of the problem so far.

Comment: This worked for me, but for any others finding this post, can you add 
        android:orientation="vertical" to the first Linear Layout in badged_tab.xml? I believe that is the desired result.

Comment: Please note that there is now a better way via the latest material components update

Comment: but this material design shows badge counter on my TabTitle ,,it looks creeep...Is there any way I can give orientation or gravity to badge counter?

Comment: For newer version for material TabLayout you can use getOrCreateBadge()
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getOrCreateBadge()
      .setNumber(1);

Comment: How to use the updated answer? I'm unable to access BadgeDrawable. What import library should I put in my gradle?

Comment: did showBadge() get removed? It's also no longer available for bottomnavigationview, but getOrCreateBadge it there

Comment: Getting @id/text is private when using the @android:id notation

Comment: 'private' error was because I changed text1 to text

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest you look at this website:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#design-support-library

You can iterate through the different tabs using this method and set the custom views to whatever you want:

```
  // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }

public View getTabView(int position) {
    // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    img.setImageResource(imageResId[position]);
    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: i tried this and its working, but if for example i selected the custom tab and want the tab to return to its default view after that (having normal and selected color) like the other tabs, how can i do that

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly fine with great explanation in the link.

Comment: it's working but how to set default width and height like other tabs?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old cuestion, but Its much more simple these days.
Im using Kotlin, AndroidX, using the next widget as TabLayout:

```
com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
```

and inside my gradel app file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

For setting a simple badge, just write..

```
yourTabLayout?.getTabAt(currentTabPosition)?.apply{
                        orCreateBadge
                        badge?.isVisible = true
                    }
```

Then just set isVisible = false to hide, like this:

```
private fun changeYourTabMethod(newTabPosition : Int) {
    // do some stuff and then hide the badge...
    yourTabLayout?.getTabAt(newTabPosition)?.apply{
        badge?.isVisible = false
    }
}
```

Comment: works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I will use this:

```
  tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getOrCreateBadge().setNumber(10);
```

Comment: Depreciated. not available in androidx anymore.

Comment: @SatyajitDas TabLayout is a part of Material Components for Android rather than AndroidX now. You should switch to the former.

Answer (score 3):

I don' know why but none of the above answers worked for me :(

I have my own Solution that is gonna make the same tablayout as the whatsapp with that badge :)

First make a custom tab Layout as custom_tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:padding="12dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calls"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_color_selector"
        android:textSize="@dimen/large_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_count"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="99"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second a badge_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@drawable/tab_text_color_selector" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Third a tab_color_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:color="@color/colorTextPrimary"android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
 </selector>
```

Fourth in your activity

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    try
    {
        setupTabIcons();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Fifth Define setupTabIcons and prepareTabView methods

```
  private void setupTabIcons()
{

    for(int i=0;i<tabTitle.length;i++)
    {
        /*TabLayout.Tab tabitem = tabLayout.newTab();
        tabitem.setCustomView(prepareTabView(i));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabitem);*/

        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(prepareTabView(i));
    }
    }

 String[] tabTitle={"LOL!","LOL@","LOL#"};
int[] unreadCount={1,3,3};

private View prepareTabView(int pos) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null);
    TextView tv_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    TextView tv_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_count);
    tv_title.setText(tabTitle[pos]);
    if(unreadCount[pos]>0)
    {
        tv_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_count.setText(""+unreadCount[pos]);
    }
    else
        tv_count.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    return view;
    }
```

I might have left something during answering this question, Just ping me, I would be happy to help :D

Comment: Thanks, as your case, none of above solution worked for me, but yours worked nice.

Answer (score 2):

Answer working in **2022**

Hi there,
I am bit late to answer but as of now with Material components you don't have to look for any custom view or third party library

I am using `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` with `androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2` and it is working fine

```
val requestsTab = viewBinding.tabLayout.getTabAt(2)
            val orCreateBadge = requestsTab?.orCreateBadge
            orCreateBadge?.number=10
            orCreateBadge?.backgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.blue,context?.theme)
            orCreateBadge?.badgeTextColor =  resources.getColor(R.color.white,context?.theme)
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

just use this trick :

```
BadgeView bv1 = new BadgeView(this, ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0));
```

Comment: what is BadgeView?

Comment: He is referring to the [ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/README.markdown) Library,to add badges to views.Keep in mind this library is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, works:

```
if(list.isNotEmpty()) {
    mTlSaved.getTabAt(0)?.orCreateBadge?.number = list.size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.orCreateBadge?.number = 5
```

Comment: For completeness, please always explain your answer

Answer (score -1):

I suggest use a CustomView for tabs.
you can create a new view with badge and set that to your tabs.

```
tab.setCustomView(R.layout.badged_tab);
```

Answer (score -8):

There are easy way as well. Just append a special characters behind. It will look like whatsapp does.

➀ ➁ ➂ ➃ ➄ ➅ ➆ ➇ ➈ ➉ ➊ ➋ ➌ ➍ ➎ ➏ ➐ ➑ ➒ ➓

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("News " + ➊));
```

Comment: how can i write my own number in special characters?

Comment: @Jason, then how to dynamically change that value ?

Comment: This seems only valid if the badge number is below 11 or if you create your custom font with more numbers

Comment: This seems to be not a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Even web environment doesn't use this way.

Comment: This answer must be removed