# Can a custom view be used as a TabItem?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

The TabLayout class in android provides you with a TabItem that can let you specify a text and a icon. 
Is it possible to use a custom view as a TabItem?

My tab would look like this

[image]

as you can see besides an icon and a text label, I also have a notification symbol (a number inside a yellow circle). how can I make tabs like this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In certain cases, instead of the default tab view we may want to apply a custom XML layout for each tab. To achieve this, iterate over all the TabLayout.Tabs after attaching the sliding tabs to the pager:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        SampleFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = 
            new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Next, we add the getTabView(position) method to the SampleFragmentPagerAdapter class:

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2" };
   private int[] imageResId = { R.drawable.ic_one, R.drawable.ic_two };

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        img.setImageResource(imageResId[position]);
        return v;
    }

}
```

With this you can setup any custom tab content for each page in the adapter.

[SOURCE](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout)

Comment: of course! can't believe i didnt see the setCustomView in Tablayout.Tab class.

Thank you

Comment: but its not working onTabChange listener, to show selected Tab with highlighted color

Comment: To change the tab text color you can create a customView and override the setSelected(boolean selected) method to change its own colors accordingly.

Comment: @Asym is there a way to do this in xml?

Comment: It wasn't useful because when you use setCustomeView, the highlighted color when you click on item, will be removed.

Comment: Have you been able to get this working with `ViewPager2` and `TabLayout`?

Answer (score 5):

you can use any layout for each tab item. Firstly add TabItems to TabLayout like that; (my layout has 2 textview and 1 image for each tab)

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/ti_payroll_tab_tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/your_custom_layout" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/ti_payroll_tab_tab2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/your_custom_layout" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Then you must find and set views in custom layout.

```
TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);

tvTab1Title = tab1.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.txt_payroll_tab_title);
tvTab1Value = tab1.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.txt_payroll_tab_value);
ivTab1 = tab1.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.img_payroll_tab_image);
```

Comment: How to add this custom tab dynamically?

Comment: What is the point of using the ```android:layout``` attribute if you're going to manually set it up?

Answer (score 3):

Documents are very poor on this topic. We can use `setCustomView` method of tabs to set custom view. Following is a working example:

**tab_layout.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark" />
```

**custom_tab_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/tab_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabTitle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tabIcon"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_item)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tabIcon)
                        ?.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab1)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tabTitle)?.setText(R.string.tab1)
                }
                1 -> {
                    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_item)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tabIcon)
                        ?.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab2)
                    tab.customView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tabTitle)
                        ?.setText(R.string.tab2)
                }
            }
        }.attach()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use code below

```
private View mCustomView;
private ImageView mImageViewCustom;
private TextView mTextViewCustom;
private int count = 0;

public View getCustomTab() {
    mCustomView = LayoutInflater.from(NewHomePageActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    mImageViewCustom = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_imageView);
    mTextViewCustom = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_textView_count);
    if (count > 0) {
        mTextViewCustom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTextViewCustom.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    } else {
        mTextViewCustom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return mCustomView;
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_home_gray_48);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_follow_gray_48);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_follower_gray_48);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_news_event_gray_48);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setCustomView(getCustomTab());
    tabLayout.getTabAt(5).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_menu_gray_48);
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_tab_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_bell_gray_48"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_dsc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_tab_textView_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: How do you access the views in the customView from the onTabSelected method call to apply a style?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - the icon in the tab had been to small and there was no way to make it bigger. I found an alternative of Özer Özcans answer the easiest. The key is the statement   android:layout="@layout/your_custom_layout". One can make 3 different custom layouts for 3 different tabs. That way -everything-  can be done in xml. To make it easy use a "shared" layout for your first tests. Replicate to custom_layout2,3 and
just change the icon drawable names. This offers full control.
The only thing that would -not- work is the yellow circle counter in Denny´s question, as this is dynamic. If you need that Özers answer is again the best.

Here are the xml snippets:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintab"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"

            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout="@layout/tab_layout"
               />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout="@layout/tab_layout2"

                />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout="@layout/tab_layout3"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Followed by one of the 3 tab_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mytabIcon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:scaleX= "0.5"
    android:scaleY= "0.5"
    android:src="@drawable/basis_tab"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:tint="@color/whitecream" />
```

Scaling the image worked nicely with scaleX and Y then.
Interestingly the Tablayout class did manage to distribute space equally in 1/3 of screenwidth, and also kept the aspect ratio of the icons. This is excellent since my drawables are big images (so they could explode the layout), while i set a fixed dp width in
android:layout_width="100dp". The  Tablayout class nicely expands this to the full screen width (which can be variable).
Obviously noone wants distorted icons. I also tested what Tablayout does when the width is to small - it then starts to scale down the tab icon.