# TabLayout inside ViewPager prohibits swiping

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, android-scrollview, android-tablayout

I have the following `ViewPager`'s **FINANCIAL** fragment page.

[image]

It is built using the following mythology

```
this.detailedStockFragmentPagerAdapter = new DetailedStockFragmentPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), bundle);
viewPager.setAdapter(detailedStockFragmentPagerAdapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(Math.max(1, detailedStockFragmentPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1));
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

private static class DetailedStockFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public DetailedStockFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle bundle) {
        super(fm);
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            {
                ...
            }
            case 1:
            {
                ...
            }
            case 2:
            {
                FinancialFragment financialFragment = FinancialFragment.newInstance();
                financialFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                return financialFragment;
            }
            default:
                assert(false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return JStockApplication.instance().getString(R.string.info);
            case 1:
                return JStockApplication.instance().getString(R.string.news);
            case 2:
                return JStockApplication.instance().getString(R.string.financial);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In **FINANCIAL** page, there are 3 components

1. Button
2. TextView
3. inner TabLayout (The bar with 1D, 1W, 1M, 3M, ...)

If I touch any of the following components, and swipe toward right, it works as expected.

1. Button
2. TextView
3. Any empty area of the fragment

[image]

---

***However, if my touch area is inner `TabLayout`, swipe doesn't work. It seems that the `TabLayout` has "eaten" my swipe event.***

Any idea how I can have inner `TabLayout` in `ViewPager` fragment, yet doesn't affect my swipe event?

The XML of my `ViewPager` fragment page is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is button"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="This fragment is not scrollable. How to make toolbar visible?"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/period_tablayout_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/period_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TradingChartPeriodTabTextAppearance"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabBackground="?attr/tradingHistorySummaryChartBackgroundColor"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/primaryTextColor">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_1d"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_day_1_short" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_1w"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_week_1_short" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_1m"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_month_1_short" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_3m"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_months_3_short" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_6m"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_months_6_short" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_1y"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_year_1_short" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_5y"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_years_5_short" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tab_item_10y"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/trading_period_max" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post your code of `FinancialFragment` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TabLayout` is a subclass of `HorizontalScrollView`, which in turn is a subclass of `ScrollView`. If you [disable horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5763815/1083957), then the `MotionEvent` won't be swallowed by `TabLayout`, instead would be passed higher up the view hierarchy - to `ViewPager`.

You can subclass `TabLayout` performing following changes:

```
    public class MyTabLayout extends TabLayout {

        public MyTabLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            switch (ev.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    return false;
                default:
                    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @azizbekian, 
you disabled the scroll for tab on ACTION_DOWN event, this will also disable the vertical scroll of tablayout.

Comment: @AmitBhati, `TabLayout` does not have vertical scrolling, neither OP needs it in his use case.

Comment: TabLayout may contains child fragment that may contains any scrollview

Comment: @Amit Bhati, I'm not sure that's possible to do. Judging by [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), `TabLayout` expects only a `TabItem`. Nevertheless, if you apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897198/1083957) approach, then judging by [sources of `TabView#onMeasure()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java#1583), there are **no** constraints on `heightMeasureSpec`, scrollview should be completely laid out.

Comment: I think that my solution takes care of these cases and should be the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

I think the following works:

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    private PointF touchStartPoint;
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private boolean mIsScrolling;

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        config();

    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        config();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        config();

    }

    private void config() {
        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
        mTouchSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            touchStartPoint = new PointF(ev.getX(), ev.getY());

            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            mIsScrolling = false;
            return false;
        }

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (mIsScrolling) {
                    return false;
                }
                final int xDiff = calculateDistanceX(ev);
                if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                    mIsScrolling = true;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private int calculateDistanceX(MotionEvent ev) {
        return (int) Math.abs(ev.getX() - touchStartPoint.x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Viewpager inside your FinantialFragment After Changing Your FinancialFragment should be like below :

```
public class FinancialFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private View rootView;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.period_tab_layout);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapters adapter = new ViewPagerAdapters(getChildFragmentManager() );
        adapter.addFragment(new OneDayFragment(), "1D");
        adapter.addFragment(new OneWeekFragment(), "1W");
        adapter.addFragment(new OneMonthFragment(), "1M");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeMonthFragment(), "3M");
        adapter.addFragment(new SixMonthFragment(), "6M");
        adapter.addFragment(new OneYearFragment(), "1Y");
        adapter.addFragment(new FiveYearFragment(), "5Y");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(Math.max(1, adapter.getCount() - 1));
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapters extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapters(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

And Yout layout should be like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is button"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="This fragment is not scrollable. How to make toolbar visible?"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/period_tablayout_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/period_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```