# How can I add Remove Icon on TabLayout.Tab to delete Tab by clicking added Remove Icon

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I am implementing a view with TabLayout and Recycler View.
Each tab will contains individual items in a Recycler View related to currently selected tab.
What I am searching is, I want to remove all items belong to the selected Tab and remove the Tab that pressed delete icon in TabLayout Tab.

I know how to remove a tab from tab layout.
But I do not have any idea, how to show a remove icon on each Tab and when I press remove Icon how can I remove the specific Tab and its Data.

**Below given image is from a web view, I have to do exact same thing in Android.**

*Question in summary*,

1. Add a delete icon to TabLayout.Tab
2. When click delete icon, that TabLayout.Tab shoul remove from TabLayout.

[image: Expected result is underlined with red color on the image]

Please give me some ideas or guides.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following way :

1. During callback of [**`TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html)

   Method [**`onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html#ontabselected) will provide you **selected tab**. so find your close icon from it using `findViewById` and then set click listener on it.

   During method [**`onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html#ontabunselected) you can remove click listener for particular close icon.
2. During click event of your close button,

   You can get **selected tab index** using [**`getSelectedTabPosition()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#getselectedtabposition). So using that index you can remove that tab,

   To remove buttons from all of tabs you can iterate through all tabs using combination of [`getTabAt (int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#gettabat) & [`getTabCount ()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout#gettabcount) methods from `TabLayout` then remove it one by one and after that also remove tab and it's data after that in this click listener.

Yes, there's no easy way to do this stuff but it'll help like patchy way.

Comment: I am appreciating your answer, but, is there any way to add delete icon to TabLayout.Tab? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can provide custom tab to your `TabLayout`. Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897198/10271334