# How to add badget to TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In my application i want use [this library](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) for use TabLayout.

I want add badget to Tabs, such as this image. please see below image to understand my mean :  
[image]

How can i it? Please help me.

Comment: https://github.com/LiushuiXiaoxia/TabLayoutPlus

Comment: https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout#how-to-customize-the-tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Tablayout tabs with notification badge like whatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968162/android-tablayout-tabs-with-notification-badge-like-whatsapp)

Comment: @배준모, can you send me code? please